# Изменение размеров формы при установленном BackGroundImage

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте.Установил изображение как BackGroundImage формы.
При изменении размеров формы изображение моргает при прорисовке,можно как-то это исправить?Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Задайте у формы свойство `DoubleBuffered = true;`

Comment: и еще проверьте, что изображение имеет не слишком большое (4000х4000 лучше сразу обрезать до максимально необходимого если конечно экран не поддерживает такие разрешения) разрешение, т.к. операция масштабирования в GDI+ тоже довольно тяжелая.